# Inconsistent C style string output between different operating systems / compilers

Tags: c++, c++11, g++

I have a C++ program:

```
#include <iostream>

char * foo (char * bar, const char * baz) {
    int i = -1;

    do {
        i++;    
        *(bar + i) = *(baz + i);
    } while (*(baz + i));

    return bar;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char bar[] = "";
    char baz[] = "Hello";

    foo(bar, baz);

    std::cout << "bar: " << bar << std::endl;
    std::cout << "baz: " << baz << std::endl;
}
```

Not that this is the important part, but the requirement for this program is that it copies one [C style string](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/66-c-style-strings/) into another using pointers.

When I compile and execute my binary on my Ubuntu 16.04 desktop, this is what I see:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test && ./test
bar: Hello
baz: ello
```

Egad! The initial `'H'` of `baz` has been dropped, but I don't see how my `foo` function changes `baz` at all. Hmm...

The g++ version on my Ubuntu desktop is thus:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I thought this was an error or bug with my code (and it may still be), yet I discovered that when I compile and run on any other operating system I get different behavior.

Here is the output on macOS:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test && ./test
bar: Hello
baz: Hello
```

Here is the g++ version on that macOS laptop:

```
$ g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

When tested on other Linux boxes, on Windows, etc. it has the correct, expected out put of `bar` and `baz` both being `Hello`.

What is going on!?

**tl;dr** C++ program outputs a C style string differently on my desktop than any other computer. Why?

Comment: `char bar[] = "";` isn't a very big string. Copying anything into it is likely to result in buffer overflow and your friend and mine, [Undefined  Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). Since the behaviour of a program with Undefined Behaviour is undefined, reasoning about inconsistent behaviour is a a questionable expenditure of time..

Comment: Side note: you may find `while (*baz) { *bar++ = *baz++; }` a little easier on the brain. While there's a non-zero value at `baz` get the value at `baz` then advance `baz` to the next character. Store the value into the value at `bar`, and then advance `bar`.

Comment: You might want to specify a length for `bar` between `[` and `]`.

Comment: @user4581301: the only issue with that (albeit canonical) loop is you have to then transfer the `\0` after the loop.

Comment: @SolomonUcko I presume you mean the `bar` that's a local variable in `name`, not the `bar` that's a parameter to `foo`.

Comment: @KeithThompson Yep, sorry for not being clear.

Comment: @user4581301 It was a given requirement that I use a do-while loop and not a while loop. I agree that a while loop would be easier on the brain. Unfortunately I wasn't making the rules for how this program was made.

Comment: Sleep, `do`/`while` works a bit better here anyway for reasons pointed out by paxdiablo's comment a few comments up. If you test for the null terminator and exit after copying the null terminator, you don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
char bar[] = "";
```

This guarantees to create a region of memory one byte long (basically just long enough to hold the `'\0'`). An implementation *may* give you more but you cannot rely on that.

Hence it's not big enough to store the string `"Hello"`, which would require six bytes. This is covered in, for example, `C++20 [expr.add]`, with my added emphasis:

> If the expression `P` points to element `x[i]` of an array object `x` with `n` elements, the expressions `P + J` and `J + P` (where `J` has the value `j`) point to the (possibly-hypothetical) element `x[i + j]` if `0 <= i + j <= n`; ***otherwise, the behavior is undefined.***

If you want to ensure there's enough space in *this* code snippet, you can just change the declarations to:

```
char baz[] = "Hello";
char bar[sizeof(baz)];  // bar will be same size as baz
```

For other scenarios, there are different ways to guarantee this size but the general rule is still the same: make sure the destination array is big enough so that you don't write beyond the end of it.

---

Although undefined behaviour means anything can happen, what's most *likely* happening in your errant case is to do with the following memory layout on the stack. You copy characters one-by-one from `baz` to `bar` (with `$` representing the `\0` character), resulting in the following before and after snapshots:

```
     bar
      V
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
    | $ | H | e | l | l | o | $ |  (before)
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
    | H | e | l | l | o | $ | $ |  (after)
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
          ^
         baz
```

So you can see how writing beyond the end of `bar` can affect other things on the stack like `baz`. If the stack layout were *different,* the effects will most likely also be different.

For example, if `bar` and `baz` were on the stack in the *other* order, then `bar` would *not* affect `baz`. It would almost certainly affect something *else* on the stack, resulting in weird behaviour, especially if that something else happened to be something like a return address to a calling function :-)

The bottom line is, undefined behaviour means exactly that - you cannot rely on anything working as expected.